# Windows server 2012 r2 IIS PHP

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I have php installed on a windows server 2012 r2 box that is running IIS

When running a script with a mail function it will hang and eventually bring this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout
```

It will run for around ten minutes before producing this error, just to clarify the script is only one line at the moment and should take less than a second to execute.

Can anyone point me in the right direct as to why the mail() function isn't running correctly?

Extra info:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_path = "C:\php\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

The fakesendmail works on WAMP server

Comment: Why are you trying to use SednMail.exe on Windows? In the PHP.ini itself it even says "For Unix only". Do you have an actual SMTP server setup on Localhost?

Comment: Yes I am using some software called fake sendmail. Here: http://glob.com.au/sendmail/‎   Everything is set up correctly but it doesn't get that far as I can see no logs which it normally produces

Comment: If you use the sendmail.exe from the command-line to send an email does it work as expected?  Do you have the debug log for that sendmail program enabled in the INI?